# How to change Windows resolution scaling using python

Tags: python, winapi, automation, pywin32, pyautogui

I'm trying to create a script that would automate a workflow with Python, I'm using `PyAutoGui` to find a image on screen and it locates and clicks on it.

The problem is that it will work with machines with my display settings (1920x1080, 100% scale), and will fail to locate when the scaling is changed (resolution can change, and it will work fine though). There's a good answer explaining how it works here: [Running Pyautogui on a different computer with different resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302681/running-pyautogui-on-a-different-computer-with-different-resolution).

If the problem is with scaling, how can I programmatically do this step-by-step, that would work with any kind of display settings? I couldn't find any definitive answers so far:

Something that could do this with Python:

1. Start the program, get and save current scaling to variable
2. Change scaling to 100%
3. ..... Code
4. Change scaling back to how it was and end the program

Comment: It would seem reasonable to identify the issue prior to solving it.

Comment: The issue is with scaling, there seems to be no way to change resolution scaling on Windows with Python, no direct pythonic way after searching through documentations. I'm trying to find a workaround if there is one, a way to access the display settings and tweak the scaling with a executable

Comment: The issue is that your calculations are wrong. You'll want to fix those calculations, or—preferably—use an automation interface that doesn't rely on coordinates at all (such as the `"uia"` backend). Changing the user's scaling is applying a global solution to a local problem.

Comment: I'm using Pywinauto to detect some elements with backend in this script, I really like working with it, but unfortunately not all things are found with it. For instance I want a menu item to be selected from navigation bar, and it will find the navigation bar element as a whole, not the elements that I need inside the element.  Tried to extend to those elements with failure, that's why I'm using PyAutoGUI for these tasks and it works fine together with PyWinAuto, until you come across resolutions and scaling that is...

Comment: Ugh, I just noticed you are using PyAutoGUI. That's not an automation library, for any definition of automation. At the very least, use pywinauto the the `"uia"` backend. You'll quickly understand that you do not need to know or care about coordinates. If instead you wish to continue down the road of demise, using PyAutoGUI, you'll have to let the system know that you can [handle the truth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).