# 'ImageNotFoundException' consistently across different computers when using 'pyautogui.locateOnScreen'?

Tags: python, exception, pyautogui

On one computer, the code works as follows

```
try:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/next.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8) is not None:
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.8))
        pyautogui.press("z")
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}Action.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/close.png', grayscale=False, confidence=0.8) is not None:
        locationIVS = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/close.png', confidence=0.8)
        # Capture screenshot and save it
        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

but when I try to run the same code on another computer, if it does not find "img/next.png", it throws an exception instead of going through the elif

To make it work on the second computer, I had to do the botched job below.

```
try:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img/next.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) is not None:
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.8))
        locationNext = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/next.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8)
        pyautogui.moveTo(locationNext)
        pyautogui.click()
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}Action.{Style.RESET_ALL}")

except:
    pass
try:
    if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/close.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) is not None:
        locationIVS = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('img/close.png', confidence=0.8)
        # Capture screenshot and save it
        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
except:
    pass
```

The versions of the libraries are the same and the resolutions are the same
Any idea why this is happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to use (or build) an absolute path to the image.

Comment: _it does not find "img/next.png"_ Do you mean that image **file** is not found on the disk, or do you mean the image is not found **onscreen**?  Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: is not found onscreen

"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69426639/9554981 When you change scaling on a different computer, you will need to either match the scaling or retake the screenshots for it to find them. It is default behavior in pyautogui to throw an exception when the image is not found.

Comment: I have redone the photos on the new computer with their respective resolution, but if it doesn't find the image on the screen it throws the exception anyway instead of continuing to run and trying to find the next one.

Comment: Yes that is the default behavior of pyautogui when it cannot find an image. From the docs: "NOTE: As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the provided image, they’ll raise ImageNotFoundException instead of returning None." https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html